# AJAX-ing a file outside public folder in node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I have a node.js application where I need to Ajax a file located in 'views' folder. But turns out that my jQuery code returns 404 - Not found error if the file is stored anywhere outside the public (holding static content) folder.

Here's the jQuery code:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#startButton').click(function(){
                $('#container').load('q1.html', function(response, status, xhr){
                    alert(xhr.statusText);
                });
            })
        })
```

If I place 'q1.html' in 'views' folder, then load() returns 404. It works only when I place it in the public folder (which I don't want because I don't want anyone to access the file directly from url).
Is there a way I can place the file anywhere outside public and still get it to work?

Comment: No. The file would need to be publicly available for it to be accessible from the request. There are ways to secure the content, but these would all need to be done server side and are a lot more involved than just amending some JS code to send an AJAX request (ie. user accounts/auth token generation and verification etc)

Comment: You mention that this is a node.js application but that looks like client side code to me. If you want the client (i.e the browser) to be able to access a document, it must be accessible in the document root. The fact that it is an AJAX request makes no difference.

Comment: @Rory I don't even want registered users to view the content. It's a quiz application where questions would appear one by one and I don't want users to be able to peep into upcoming questions. Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: In that case send the user's answer to the server via AJAX and check it there. Then return the response to the client-side indicating if it was right or not. You can send the questions via AJAX in the same way, but always validate answers on the server.

Comment: Without judging whether the demand is reasonable or not,  nginx is able to give you any accessibility to static files. Just set a proxy_pass to location '/xxx'.

Comment: @dunhuang That's not going to make them accessible via AJAX only as the OP is hoping for. As mentioned, the current desired setup is _not_ possible. You can't have documents accessible via AJAX but not via entering the URL in the browser.